# Microsoft AJAX Date and moment.js not giving proper local time

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-ajax, momentjs

I have a date stored in my DB in UTC. It is coming across the wire in JSON as `"/Date(1471081078117)/"`. This is '8/13/2016 2:37am' in UTC time.  I'm using `moment` to parse and display it. The below two lines are what I get when I try to display the value to the client browser.

1. `moment.utc(myDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mma')` gives me `"8/13/2016
   9:37am"` which is 7 hours later than what I expect for UTC time.
2. `moment.utc(myDate).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mma')` also gives me `"8/13/2016 2:37am"` on a machine that is on Pacific Daylight time (UTC-7). I expect `"8/12/2016 7:37pm"`

It seems everything is being displayed 7 hours later to the client than I expect.  I think moment is doing what it's supposed to do. I believe what is happening is that javascript is binding the value from the DB as a local date-time, assuming that what's coming through the wire is a local value, but what comes out of the DB is actually UTC.  How do I keep javascript from doing this?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: "By default, moment parses and displays in local time." does it work if you remove .utc?

Comment: No, we ended up parsing the date-time from the DB as a string, added a Z, forced it into a UTC moment and then went from there. Total hack.